# How to convert the amr file to mp3 (or any html5 supported format) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, amr

I have a project based on javascript.I want to play some amr files in the browser.But the amr is not supported by html5.How to convert them on the front-end or back-end?

Comment: ffmpeg might be able to do so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763080/amr-to-mp3-conversion-with-ffmpeg

Comment: If it isn't a one time job, you would probably be better of using a backend solution, like ffmpeg. Call it with the right arguments.