# Convert amr to mp3 with ffmeg on ubuntu - Input/output error

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, mp3, amr

I want to convert `amr` to `mp3`. I am following after this question:

> [AMR to MP3 conversion with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763080/amr-to-mp3-conversion-with-ffmpeg)

and typing:

```
ffmpeg -i example.amr -ar 22050 example.mp3
```

But output contains errors:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[amr @ 0x2034540] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, amr, from 'example.amr':
  Duration: 00:00:35.30, bitrate: 12 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: amr_nb (samr / 0x726D6173), 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 12 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'example.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (amr_nb (amrnb) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
example.amr: Input/output error
size=     138kB time=00:00:35.31 bitrate=  32.1kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:138kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.160448%
```

How to fix this?

#### Update - fastest method of update `ffmpeg`

To update `ffmpeg` on Ubuntu 16 use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Source

> http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/05/install-ffmpeg-3-3-in-ubuntu-16-04-14-04/

Comment: What happens when you run `ffmpeg -i example.amr example.mp3` ?

Comment: Try with another AMR file, and also with the output of `ffmpeg -i example.amr -c copy new.amr`

Comment: I obtained the same error (Input/output error) in both cases: without -ar option and with -c option. File is obtained from:

http://samplephotovideo.com/2015/12/download-amr-adaptive-multi-rate-codec-file/

But I have the same error for other files generated from phone calls.

Comment: I have also the same problem with amr file from this source: http://techslides.com/sample-files-for-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ffmpeg version is old. [Upgrade](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) to a recent git build. I don't get any errors with a current version.

Comment: You are awesome. Than you very much!