# ffmpeg mp3 conversion failed

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, flv

using ffmpeg to convert from flv to mp3 gives the following result

```
] ffmpeg-0.6.1 >> ffmpeg -i name.flv name.mp3
FFmpeg version 0.6.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
built on Feb 14 2011 12:33:38 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
configuration:
libavutil 50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
libavcodec 52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
libavformat 52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
libavdevice 52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
libswscale 0.11. 0 / 0.11. 0
[flv @ 0x10869420]Could not find codec parameters (Video: 0x0000)
[flv @ 0x10869420]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'name.flv':
Metadata:
audiocodecid : 5
duration : 10
videocodecid : -1
canSeekToEnd : true
Duration: 00:00:10.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: 0x0000, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 8000 Hz, mono, s16
Output #0, mp3, to 'name.mp3':
Stream #0.0: Audio: 0x0000, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
Encoder (codec id 86017) not found for output stream #0.0
```

you can see in last line it says codec id 86017 not found.
when i run following command:

```
ffmpeg -formats > ffmpeg-format.txt
```

mp3 is listed in available formats as 
DE mp3             MPEG audio layer 3
.What can be the error.is it that mp3 codec is not properly installed?Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your FFMPEG wasn't compiled with libmp3lame. See this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/196857/how-to-install-libmp3lame-for-ffmpeg

If you can't compile it on your own you'll have to search for a binary that does support it.

Answer (score 81):

Try this, it worked for me.

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-52

thanks to [ffmpeg: convert audio-only flv to swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268347/ffmpeg-convert-audio-only-flv-to-swf)

Comment: Great solution, had to change package to `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53` on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I tried libavcodec-extra-52 on Ubuntu 11.04 but it says "Package 'libavcodec-extra-52' has no installation candidate"

Comment: @gentrobot see above. helped for 12.10 as well

Comment: 1) For the latest Ubuntu, this is libavcodec-extra-53
2) This command may tell about a lot of conflicts and suggest awkward "solutions" involving uninstalling glibc. To overcome this, first run "sudo aptitude remove ffmpeg" and then reinstall it with "sudo aptitude install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53"

Answer (score 17):

For ubuntu 11.10:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53
```

For ubuntu 11.04, 10.10, 10.04:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-52
```

Comment: I tried libavcodec-extra-52 on Ubuntu 11.04 but it says "Package 'libavcodec-extra-52' has no installation candidate"

Comment: 12.04 is the same as for 11.10

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-*` worked on 12.10